# UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403 - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, cartalyst-sentinel

I am new to Laravel and am building a small project as my schooling. I have struck the above error and I cannot seem to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

I am using sentinel package for authentication.

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('/login' , 'LoginController@login');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request){
       Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
       return Sentinel::check();

}
```

When I click on submit button then this error showing:

> UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403:
>   The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem .

Actually i forget to replace email to username in EloquentUser.php because i am using username unique rather than email .

```
 protected $loginNames = ['email']; ->  protected $loginNames = ['username'];
```